# How to draw a circle using arcs in createjs?

Tags: easeljs, createjs

How to draw an arc in createJS. I have gone through arcTo function but its not what i want. I want to be able to draw several arcs which when put together resembles a circle. 
for Ex: I want to be able to draw a circle using 8 arcs. not able to do it using ArcTo function. Please some one suggest me a way to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arcTo function draws directly from the specified point. The `arc()` function is what you are looking for.

Here is a quick sample that draws random segments.
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/nJKHk/

```
shape.graphics.arc(0,0,50,startAngle,endAngle);
```

here is another sample with random color fills.
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/nJKHk/1/